# web.config batch="false"

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, web-config, .net-1.1

What is the purpose of adding the batch="false" in the compilation tag in ASP.NET 1.1?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

MSDN says the purpose of the batch flag

> eliminates the delay caused by the compilation required when you
>   access a file for the first time. When this attribute is set to True,
>   ASP.NET precompiles all the uncompiled files in a batch mode, which
>   causes an even longer delay the first time the files are compiled.
>   However, after this initial delay, the compilation delay is eliminated
>   on subsequent access of the file.

Having it set to false will probably make it compile faster the first time, but slower subsequent times, and I believe this applies to 1.1 as well.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0.aspx)

Answer (score 14):

I know this question is closed (and about v1.1) but the batch attribute is actually defaulted to True in .Net 2.0 onwards.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0%28VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

In asp.net 1.1, when you compile in "batch mode" set to true, the output of the source files is compiled into single assemblies according to the directories, the type of file, etc. When "batch mode" is turned off, the output is a single assembly for the entire project. 
Some of the advantages and disadvantages are described in this [small paragraph from an MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479312.aspx#issue29).

> There are several issues you should be aware of when using this
>   attribute.
>
> - Performance—when Batch=false, the ASP.NET compiler will create an assembly for every Web form and user control in your Web application.
>     It also causes the compiler to do a full compile, not an incremental
>     compile, in Visual Studio 2005 when you build using F5. The net result
>     is your Web application may run slower when deployed, and your build
>     times will increase significantly in Visual Studio 2005.
> - Assembly References—the Batch attribute may hide potential broken assembly references (when Batch=True), or even introduce a Circular
>     Reference (when Batch=False).

Comment: I'm getting circular references, which go away if I set `Batch="false"`. Just trying to figure out if I should leave it that way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the default is false (is in 2.0+) so the point of adding `batch=false` would be as a documentation of the default, or as a placeholder so it's obvious what to change if you want true.

Comment: The question was for ASP.NET 1.1