# Performance implications of setting batch=false? WCF Service is Recompiling even if Batch Mode is true

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis-6

I have a wcf service hosted on my website (Windows Server 2003 with iis 6, Dot Net Framework 4.0).

When I deploy this service, it runs on the production server.
But after a day, this service stops & I get an error :

> The service could not be activated due to an exception during
>   compilation. The Exception Message is. Could not load file or assembly
>   App_web_jm4, Version = 0.0.0.0. The system cannot find the file
>   specified.

To solve this, I had to make an **iis restart** (a very bad solution) coz still I got this error the next day.

Somewhere I read that changing this tag of web.Config solves the problem :

```
<compilation targetFramework="4.0"  batch="false">
```

It indeed solved my problem.

But I want to know :

1) Are there any performance implications of above solution to my website because the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) does not say much about the impact when value of this batch setting is false.

2) Are there any other solutions available ?

[These](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759927/the-service-cannot-be-activated-due-to-an-exception-during-compilation) [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578368/wcf-service-dies-on-its-own-after-some-time) did not help me.

**EDIT :**
Since It is classified as a duplicate of [web.config batch="false"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667653/web-config-batch-false):

This is what I understood from that post :

**Batch mode = true** -> The Compiler compiles all files separately for the first time & subsequent  request come from there.

**Batch mode  = false** -> The Compiler compiles all files together.

That means I incur a performance penalty & is not a good solution to my problem..

But About the second part :

The documentation says

> When this attribute is set to True, ASP.NET precompiles all the
>   uncompiled files in a batch mode,  which causes an even longer delay
>   the first time the files are compiled.  However, after this initial
>   delay, the compilation delay is eliminated on subsequent access of the
>   file.

When BatchMode is true (the default) then Why is it attempting to recompile the service ? 
( As The exception says "error during compilation" )

Am I missing out something ?

Comment: When you change the web.config what do you change it **from**?

Comment: I added Batch=false. in that line

Comment: Related: [web.config batch=“false”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667653/web-config-batch-false)

Comment: These two links suggest to add batch="false" to improve the performance which make me confused: [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=1YLp0JDGwUMC&pg=PT515&lpg=PT515&dq=batch%20false%20performance&source=bl&ots=D3elRxf1ZW&sig=rrA0CooNU3gCH8UdOCpw0QRs8Mg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNvv6hyM_YAhXNu1MKHR-oDLAQ6AEIcDAJ#v=onepage&q=batch%20false%20performance&f=false) and [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/perfworld/2010/01/13/how-can-i-disable-batch-compilation-for-my-asp-net-web-pages-so-that-the-first-user-accessing-the-web-site-doesnt-experience-slow-performance/)